# call template function with async

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

need to run a function asynchronously, when function takes template argument. Code below does not compile, any help?

```cpp
 template<typename T>
 void say(int n, T t) { 
    cout << " say: " << n << " " << t << endl;
 }

 template<typename F, typename... Ts>
 inline auto reallyAsync(F&& f, Ts&&... params){
   return std::async(
       std::launch::async,
       std::forward<F>(f),
       std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
 }

 int main() {
   int n = 10; float x = 100;
   say(n, x); // works
   reallyAsync(&say, n, x) ; // does not work
 }
```

Comment: It would help to add the error the compiler throws out

Comment: @Stormenet or which compiler was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`say` is a *function-template*, you cannot take the address of a *function-template* because its not yet a *function* (see comments):

```
int main() {
   int n = 10; float x = 100;
   say(n, x);                // works because of template argument deduction
   reallyAsync(&say, n, x);  //fails because say isn't a resolved  function.
 }
```

you can however, pass an instantiation of *say*:

```
 int main() {
   int n = 10; float x = 100;
   say(n, x);                     // works
   reallyAsync(&say<decltype(x)>, n, x);
 }
```

Outputs:

```
say: 10 100
say: 10 100
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4292289602e5724a)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `say` is not a function, it is a function template. You cannot get an address of a template with `&`.

Just change:

```
reallyAsync(&say, n, x)
```

to:

```
reallyAsync(&say<float>, n, x)
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
reallyAsync(&say, n, x)
```

`say` is a template. In C++, you can't take an address of a template. This is a meaningless proposition.

It is important to understand the difference between a template, and a template instance. A template is nothing more than a specification, of sorts. It doesn't exist in any real or meaningful term. And the address-of operator can only work with real, actual objects, that exist somewhere, in some-fashion.

To eliminate the compilation error, you'll have to **instantiate** the template, turning it into something tangible:

```
reallyAsync(&say<float>, n, x);
```

From your point of view this may not be ideal, and defeats the purpose of template functions. There's probably a better, different way to do whatever you're really trying to accomplish, that does not require explicit template instantiation.